# How to clear duplicated entries in SSH known_hosts and authorized_keys files?

Tags: ssh, openssh

My google search results little helpful so I asked here.

My Ubuntu server now has many duplicated entries in both files `~/.ssh/authorzied_keys` and `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

I wonder if there is a command/utility to remove those duplicated lines and list them once only?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The commandline utilities are called `uniq` and `sort`. You can simply pipe the file through them to get only unique entries:

```
sort ~/.ssh/authorized_keys | uniq > ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.uniq
```

and then replace the old file with the new one:

```
mv ~/.ssh/authorized_keys{.uniq,}
```

The `~/.ssh/known_hosts` are handled by `ssh` itself and should not contain any duplicates (if you modified it by hand, it can and then you can use the same approach as above).

Comment: Your command should not take into account the comment part (the optional last field in a line) which may vary arbitrarily

Comment: @xhienne yes, in ideal case, if this would be a problem in the authorized keys. The known hosts do not have comments.

Answer (score 5):

`ssh-keygen -R hostname` will remove the entry for specified hostname

Comment: Upvote.  Simple to te point.  Then the connection can be reestablished with `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub othersysname` like  normal.

Comment: This can work only with `known_hosts`.

Comment: Actually, `ssh-keygen -R hostname` will only remove ONE entry (the last one?). If there are multiple entries in the known_hosts file, the others will still be there.

Comment: @ScottieH `man ssh-keygen` states '-R Removes all keys belonging to the specified hostname (with optional port number) from a known_hosts file.'

Answer (score 4):

My issue was with multiple entries from one host with different host keys.  This was from a Jenkins build slave. App server was rebuilt.  Hostname/IP was moved to new server but the host keys were different.  Here's the one liner I came up with:

```
cat known_hosts | cut -f1 -d' ' | sort | uniq -c | \ 
sed '/^ *1 /d' | awk '{print $2}' | while read line; do \
ssh-keygen -R $line; ssh-keyscan $line; \
done
```

Take the first field in known_hosts, sort it, `uniq -c` to count instances of each hostname, `sed` to delete any lines with a count of 1, then `ssh-keygen -R` to remove the host, and finally `ssh-keyscan` to add the current host-key back to known_hosts.

WARNING: If you did not expect the host keys to change, then you should figure out why they did before running this.  Host keys are there to ensure you're connecting to the host you're expecting to (and not some man in the middle host).

Comment: HI Kevin Bott -  I get an incompleted "open" brackets return (prompt) ">" when I run that command 

    user@host:~$ cat known_hosts | cut -f1 -d' ' | sort | uniq -c | \ sed '/^ *1 /d' | awk '{print $2}' | while read line; do \ ssh-keygen -R $line; ssh-keyscan $line; \ done
     >

Comment: @CRTLBREAK Try removing all the '\'.  They are used for line continuation to break the long command into separate lines, but I think they're causing issues for you.

Comment: many thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 3):

An addition for **hashed known_hosts** files.

In hashed know_hosts files the hostname is hashed with a "salt". This means the lines of the same host are unique. But the `sort` command can be helpful.

Just sort the file by the third column:

```
$ sort -k3 -u ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

I tested it in Ubuntu Bionic with sort version "8.28".

```
$ ssh-keyscan -H github.com > test_known_hosts
$ wc -l test_known_hosts 
1 test_known_hosts
$ ssh-keyscan -H gitlab.com >> test_known_hosts
$ wc -l test_known_hosts 
4 test_known_hosts
$ ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> test_known_hosts
$ wc -l test_known_hosts 
5 test_known_hosts
$ sort test_known_hosts | uniq -c | wc -l
5
$ sort -k3 -u test_known_hosts | wc -l
4
```

First I add the host key from github, next from gitlab and again from github. As gitlab returns 3 keys, the sum of the keys in the file is now 5: 2 duplicate from github and 3 uniq from gitlab.

Sorting and filter the unique lines does not work with hashed host-keys, it shows still 5 lines. Means, the duplicate of github was not removed.

Sorting and filter unique lines based on the third column removes the duplicate github key from the file. Only 4 lines left instead of 5, because the duplicate of github was removed.

Comment: This is the best answer. It's short, not complicated and takes care of the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to keep one of each of the duplicates, the simplest solution is probably to just use a text editor to delete the lines of each of those files that no longer have correct information.

Comment: How do you know which ones are not correct?